# Steps down a line segment, intersecting with grid of circles analytically?

Tags: geometry

Given a regular grid of circles, where all of the circles have the same radius - some radius $r$, And given a ray starting at point $P$, with direction $V$, I need to be find the smallest time $t$ where the ray is inside of a circle.

An added complication is that I need to find the closest time $t$ which is an integer multiple of some distance $d$.

[image]

in other words, I need to find the smallest $n$ that makes $I$ be a point in a circle:

$I = P + ndV\\
n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
n \geq 0$

I know that i can solve this numerically by starting at $P$ and incrementally moving down the ray in steps of length $d$, testing to see if the resulting point is inside of a circle.  I also know that i can simplify this a bit by using modulus since all circles are identical.

However, does anyone know of any ways to do this analytically?

Comment: I assume that you have drawn just a portion of an infinitely repeating grid of circles, correct?

Comment: yes you are correct :P

Comment: I wonder if the implementation of a closed form solution (if any exists) would be in any way better than the suggested iterative approach.

Comment: Is $P$ always at the center of a square formed by the centers of four adjacent circles as in your diagram, or is moveable?

Comment: $P$ can be anywhere, and could even be inside of a circle. The analytical solution is nice because it's a fixed cost implementation in a programming language.  Even if it's more computation than the iterative solution (hoping not but...), the fixed cost aspect can be a nice quality as it can help SIMD / GPU lanes more synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem this way:

Draw a circle centered at $P$ with radius $d$. For each point of this circle lying inside one of the disks any rays from $P$ have the same time $t$ associated with how long it takes to move a distance $d$ from $P$.

Repeat with a circle centered at $P$ but with radius $2d$. Points of this circle lying on rays from $P$ not previously determined from the previous step will be associated with a time $t$ associated with the distance $2d$.

Repeat this process for a circle centered at $P$ and radius $3d$, $4d$, etc., each time including only points of the circles lying inside disks in directions not previously accounted for in previous steps.

Comment: I am misunderstanding you or I explained bad I think.  I need to know the solution for a specific V (whatever specific V value is given), I can't change the direction to get a closer result or anything like that